# Creating a column identifier based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df below as

```
    NAME 
German Rural
 1990 german
Mexican 1998
Mexican City
```

How can i create a new column based on the values of these columns ( if the column has the term %German% or % german% regardless of capital or lower case or case insensitive?

Desired output

```
NAME         | Identifier
German Rural    Euro
1990 german     Euro
Mexican 1998 South American 
Mexican City South American
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with something like the following.

```
conditions = [df["NAME"].str.lower().str.contains("german"), 
               df["NAME"].str.lower().str.contains("mexican")]

values = [ "Euro", 'South American']
    
df["identifiter"] = np.select(conditions, values, default=np.nan)

print(df)
           NAME     identifiter
0  German Rural            Euro
1   1990 german            Euro
2  Mexican 1998  South American
3  Mexican City  South American
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add, some of the columns have other text in it , is there anyway I can make it like a wildcard where it checks if that row has the term %german% , %mexican%?